# PHP Simple HTML DOM count span inside in div of other div

Tags: php, html, dom

I am using PHP Simple HTML DOM to try to count how many tags there are in an html document. The html document is structured as follows:

```html
<div class="detailMS__incidentRow incidentRow--home even">
  <div class="time-box">48'</div>
  <div class="icon-box soccer-ball">
    <span class="icon soccer-ball">&nbsp;</span>
  </div>
  <span class="participant-name">
  <a href="#" onclick="window.open('/jugador/thiago-heleno/GfhW4pOT/'); return false;">Heleno T.</a>
  </span>
  <span class="assist note-name">
    (<a href="#" onclick="window.open('/jugador/veiga-raphael/0fYAKGcN/'); return false;">Veiga R.</a>)
  </span>
</div>
```

I am trying it in the following way:

```
$es = $html->find('div[class=detailMS__incidentRow incidentRow--home even], div[class=icon-box soccer-ball] div[class=icon-box soccer-ball], span[class=icon soccer-ball]');
```

But the result is a very large array ... And the browser is blocked.

How could I get it?

Comment: Exactly which tags are you trying to count? FYI, SimpleHTMLDOM is a terrible library. See [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3577662/283366) for better alternatives

Comment: Hi phil. I am trying to count the div tags that are in other div tags. But those that have a class in particular. Why simpleHTMLDOM is a terrible library?

Comment: _“But the result is a very large array ... And the browser is blocked.”_ - well then don’t _output_ the content of the array, if that’s not what you need to begin with, but the _count_ of items it contains …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

> $MarcoGolLocal = $html->find('div[class=detailMS]
>   div[class=detailMS__incidentRow incidentRow--home even]
>   div[class=icon-box soccer-ball] span[class=icon soccer-ball]');
>
> $golesDeLocal = count($MarcoGolLocal) + count($MarcoGolLocal2);